# Devices work but integration tests say "The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project"

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I've been running my project for months on physical devices and the emulator. I just went to run my first integration test for this project by running `flutter test integration_test` and the CLI returned `The following devices were found, but are not supported by this project:`. It then listed the devices that work fine when I run my project. Why would my devices not work when running an integration test but work when running my project?

`flutter doctor` reports `Connected device (4 available)`.